# How to delete Excel files from a Unix machine?

Tags: unix

I have to delete a number of files with names like "`test excel-27-03-2016.xls`" from a directory on a Unix machine. Can you please suggest how? I tried using command

```
rm -f test excel-27-03-2016.xls
```

but it is not deleting the file.

Comment: am not getting any error. I have taken root access so I will have all permissions.

Comment: Don't switch to root if you can avoid it.  Mistakes made as root are potentially far more serious than mistakes made running as yourself. Using the `-f` option means that `rm` doesn't report errors.  When a delete doesn't work, you should drop the `-f` option so that `rm` reports what the problems are.  In this case, the problem is the spaces in the file name; it will say something like `rm: test: no such file or directory` and `rm: excel-27-03-2016.xls: no such file or directory` because it is given two separate arguments rather than one argument containing a space.

Answer (score 1):

So if '`test excel-27-03-2016.xls`' is one filename, you have to escape the space in the `rm` command.

```
rm test\ excel-27-03-2016.xls
```

or

```
rm 'test excel-27-03-2016.xls'
```

otherwise `rm` will think 'test' and 'excel-27-03-2016.xls' are two different files.
(Also you shouldn't need to use `-f`.)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. But I have 20-30 files of such do I have to give rm 'test excel-27-03-2016.xls" each time and provide "Yes" permission to delete file.. Do u have any other suggestion?

Comment: You can try using the wildcard, *.

Comment: If all your files look like 'test excel-...', you can do `rm -f 'test excel-*'`

Comment: Using `rm -f 'test excel-*'` won't work; it will attempt to move a file with a `*` at the end of its name.  You could use `rm -f 'test excel-'*` (note that the `*` is outside the single quotes, not inside as it was before), and that will work.  Wild-card expansion doesn't happen inside (double or single) quotes.  No expansions happen inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Does the name of the file contains a space? It seems so.
If this is the case, `rm -f "test excel-27-03-2016.xls"` (note double quotes around the file name) ought to do it.

Running `rm -f test excel-27-03-2016.xls` means trying to erase two files, one named `test` and the other `excel-27-03-2016.xls`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. do I have to give double quotes each time to delete multiples files for example rm -f "test excel-27-03-2016.xls" "test1 excel-27-03-2016.xls"

Comment: Yes, double quotes for every file with spaces on it. I suggest checking some basic regular expressions, for example, rm -f test?excel*.xls would delete all files which names start with test, have any single character, continues with excel, have any number of characters and the extension xls. Try it first with ls -l test?excel*.xls to see if it list the ones you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, if the file name contains spaces, you have to protect those spaces.  By default, the shell splits file names (arguments in general) at spaces.  So, enclose the name in double quotes or single quotes:

```
rm -f "test excel-27-03-2016.xls"
```

or use a backslash if you prefer (but I don't prefer backslashes; I normally use quotes):

```
rm -f test\ excel-27-03-2016.xls
```

When a delete operation doesn't work, the `-f` option to `rm` becomes your enemy; it suppresses the error messages that `rm` would otherwise give.  For example, without the `-f`, you might see:

```
$ rm test excel-27-03-2016.xls
rm: test: No such file or directory
rm: excel-27-03-2016.xls: No such file or directory
$
```

That tells you that `rm` was given two names, not one as you intended.

---

From a comment:

> I have 20-30 files; do I have to give `rm 'test excel-27-03-2016.xls"` each time and provide "Yes" permission to delete file?

Time to learn wild-cards.  First thing to learn — ***Be Careful!***  Do not destroy files carelessly.

Run a command such as:

```
ls -ld *.xls
```

Does that list the files you want deleted — all the files you want deleted and nothing but the files you want deleted?  If it doesn't contain any extra file names (and no directory names), then you can run:

```
rm -f *.xls
```

If it doesn't contain all the file names you need deleted, but it does contain only names that you need deleted, then run the `rm` to reduce the size of the problem, then devise an alternative pattern to delete the others:

```
ls -ld *.xlsx   # Semi-plausible
```

If it contains too many names, you have a couple of options.  One is to use `rm` interactively:

```
rm -i *.xls
```

and respond yes to those that should be deleted and no to those that should be kept.  Another is to work out a more precise wildcard, perhaps `*-27-03-2016.xls`.

When using wild-cards, the shell keeps file names as single arguments, so the fact that the generated names have spaces in them isn't a problem.  Be aware that many shell techniques, such as capturing that list of file names in a variable, do not preserve the spaces properly — a cause of much confusion.

And, with any mass file removal, **be very careful**.  The Unix system will not stop you doing immense damage to your files  It will take you at your word — if you say 'remove everything', it will try to do so.

---

From another comment:

> I have taken root access so I will have all permissions.

Don't run as root when you have problems working out what you are doing.  Running as `root` means that any mistake has the potential to be dramatically more devastating than if you run as yourself.

If you are running as root, the `-f` option to `rm` really isn't needed (unless someone has attempted to protect you by creating an alias for the `rm` command).

When you're `root`, the system does what you tell it to do.  `root`: Remove the kernel.  `system`: Yes, sir!  Right away, sir!  `root`: Remove the complete root file system.  `system`: Yes, sir!  Right away, sir!

Be very, very careful when running as root.  It is a bad idea to experiment when running as root.  It is very important to know exactly what you plan to do as root, to gain root privileges and do what you plan to do, and then lose the root privileges as soon as possible.  Use `sudo` (or `su`) to temporarily gain root privileges.